# Bib entry making maths letters lower case

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

This question is about the reference format making letters inside maths `$  $` into lower case. As they are in standard format I want them to be uppercase.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}


\documentclass[natbib,fleqn,smallextended]{svjour3}

\begin{filecontents}{sw_ref.bib}
@article{daon,
  title={ $\delta^{18}O$ and $\delta^{13}C$: },
  author={D},
  journal={Ers},
  volume={54},
  number={3},
  pages={545},
  year={2005},
  publisher={El}
}
@article{cow,
  title={$\delta^{13}C$  measurements},
  author={Coichael},
  journal={A},
  volume={48},
  number={7},
  pages={5781},
  year={2256},
  publisher={ACtions}
}
\end{filecontents} 
%

%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % for upright CO2
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%
%setting spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\singlespacing
%\onehalfspacing
%For other sizes use the \setstretch command like this:
%\setstretch{1.8}

\raggedbottom

%line Numbers
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers*[1]
%to set numbering format
\usepackage{enumerate}
%Maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
%for deg
\usepackage{gensymb}
%for permil
\usepackage{wasysym}
% for rotating floats
\usepackage{lscape}
%for subfigures and tables
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%made commands
\newcommand{\mytilde}{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathtt{\sim}$}} %around tilde
%% Insert the name of "your journal" with

%
\begin{document}

\title{Det}
%\subtitle{}

\titlerunning{Sou}        % if too long for running head

\author{Tor}

\authorrunning{et al} % if too long for running head

\institute{Tror \at
 d \\
}

% \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\keywords{}

\end{abstract}

$\delta^{18}O$ and $\delta^{13}C$
\citep{cow}
\citep{daon}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{sw_ref}

\end{document}
```

The output (the stuff at the two ends of the red arrows should look the same):

[image]

Comment: Adding additional braces should prevent the lowercasing: `{$\delta^{18}O$} and {$\delta^{13}C$}`. BTW: the IUPAC recommends upright letters for atom symbols: `{$\delta^{18}$O} and {$\delta^{13}$C}`

Comment: I tried both {$\delta^{18}O$} / {$\delta^{13}C$} and {$\delta^{18}$O} and {$\delta^{13}$C}. no change... Also $\delta^{18}O$ is a measured quantity and in fact should not be written as \ce{CO2}

Comment: Have you made the changes in the bib file directly? LaTeX won't rewrite it when you make the changes in the `filecontents` environment _unless_ you add `\usepackage{filecontents}` before the environment.

Comment: ok, I forgot to delete the generated .bib file........... both the options work now..... Thanks a lot!!!! :D

Comment: @clemens Wanna turn your comment into an answer?